# Detect Shift+1 as Key.Add

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, input

I would like to detect the user pressing the "add" key in the .net 4 WPF KeyDown event handler. To do this I use the following test:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Add)
```

This doesn't detect the case when the user presses Shift+1 (which corresponds to "add" on my keyboard layout).
How can I detect this? I'm not convinced that testing

```
if (e.Key == Key.D1 && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
```

is the right solution as it may be mapped elsewhere on another keyboard layout.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes I did and no it didn't fire when I press Shift+1.

Comment: It is most definitely mapped elsewhere on another layout :) If add doesn't work simply see what the key is detected as - break with the debugger and inspect the eventargs when you press the key. Maybe break only inside an if block that checks if shift is pressed, to make it easier.

Comment: @Alex Paven: Of course I did that and the value of e.Key is Key.D1. But as noted in the question I don't want to use this test as it may be mapped elsewhere on another keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `KeyPress` event handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void trackBarFrames_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch ( e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Add :
            // Nummeric Keypad Add 
            AddSomething();
            break;
        case Keys.Oemplus :
            // Regular keyboard Add
            // OemPlus is assigned to the regular keyboard key with a "Add" Sign but doesn not take shift conditions in account..!
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
            {
                AddSomething();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a moment to explain this code, so someone coming along reading it later will understand it better, and what makes it an answer to the question asked?

Comment: In a german keyboard layout, the `plus` sign (+) doesn't require the `Shift` modifier, but in a UK keyboard layout it does, making this code work only for certain keyboard layouts.